# How can i convert sunburst graph as a Directive to use with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I have created a [`sunburst graph`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/tdnh4zr3/) with normal javascript.

Now i need to get the data from a service and generate the graph in AngularJS. How can I make a directive out of this? Any example or guidance will be great.

I have made a controller to get the data from the service. And the code is here:

```
 $scope.buildchart = function(widget) {
        var w2 = new Worker("scripts/webworkers/bigQueryWorker.js");           
        w2.postMessage($scope.selectedClass + "," 
          + $rootScope.hierarchystring.toString() 
          + "," + "Hierarchy" + "," + Digin_Engine_API);

        w2.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
            hierarchyRetrieved(event);
        });

        function hierarchyRetrieved(event) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(event.data);
            console.log("Hierarchy data is");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

        };
    };
```

Is there a way I could get this data inside this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** you make a directive like this:

```
<svg sunburst-chart></svg>
```

**Second**

Make a mock function for ajax like this:

```
 function mockAnAjaxCall() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $scope.data1 = {
        "name": "Root",
        "children": [{ ...
        }]
      };
        $scope.$apply();//apply the scope as data is changed.
    }, 3000); //ajax call gets over in 3 secs
```

**Third**

Make a link function to `watch` the data change on `data1` variable.

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
  //this will watch the scope data
  scope.$watch(
    "data1",//variable you are watching
    function handleChange(root, oldValue) {
                console.log(scope.data1)
      if (!root) {
        return;
      }
      //make the sun burst chart.
```

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/0j1ebntv/4/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are the D3 expert in SO :)